# PNG animation render, saving images without a file type

Tags: file-format

So this is probably a simple solve and most likely due to me adding a setting that I shouldn't have.

So for all of my other animations I have done, I render each step as a PNG image and then use the Image Sequencer to render the final animation, and it works well. But this time around, all of the rendered images are not saved as PNGs but rather saved **without a file type** but can still be opened via Chrome.

Any ideas how I can get Blender to save these renders as a PNG?

Specs:
GeForce GTX 1060 3GB,
Windows 10,
intel i7,
8GB RAM,
Blender 2.79

[image]

Comment: The files are not garbage, because they can be opened. So they have a type. But it's still possible they have no file name extension. Just in case they do, but you can't see it... have you checked View > File Name Extensions, in your Windows  file browser?

Answer (score 11):

In the Render panel in Input, check "File extensions"

(They are saved without a file *extension*, which is not the same as a file *type*.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is so stupid that this isn't the default.

Comment: This IS the default (at least in 3.x)

Comment: Was not for me when I ran into this yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the file extension was not ticked... So I checked *File Extensions* checbox in the Render tab > Output panel and now rendered images are saved with extension.