# My images are rendered as file, not PNG. How to open the files in video editing?

Tags: rendering

I rendered over 1000 images and it took over 3 hours.

But due to an Insufficient storage space, the images are saved as file, not PNG.

I can open and see the images, but I cannot open in blender in video editing.

Is there any way to open that files in blender in video editing?

Or can I change the files to PNG?

Folder:
[image]

open with:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "file, not PNG", as typically by PNG people mean a file (with .png extension). Is it saved as a file in a different format than PNG? Or is it PNG format but without the .png extension?

Comment: and with what program can you open and see the image?

Comment: I uploaded a folder that I rendered image in.

Comment: What operating system do you use (what version of Windows)? It seems you have some path problems: https://i.imgur.com/018KXuo.png I found this question on Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line

Comment: I deleted that part because that is not english. I use widow 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to add in the file extension.
for example, take the file "0351", you add a ".png" to the end so it looks like "0351.png", and check if it opens in blender.

If it works, you can batch change the file extensions using cmd in windows.

For that,

**Step 1**

Search for cmd in the start, and open it

[image]

**Step 2**

Go to your folder where these files are located and **copy** the directory

[image]

**Step 3**

```
cd (paste file location)
```

Please mind the **space** after "cd" in the above command

It would look something like this, but replace the "D:\DATA\Test" with your copied location

[image]

Press Enter

**Step 4**

If you have the files stored in a different drive (if the files are not in the same drive as you have installed windows on), you need to perform an extra step and type in the letter allocated to the drive. You can find it in "This PC" (search in start)

[image]

In this example, it's "D"

so, if yours is stored in another drive, in this example "D", type in the below command and replace "d" with the letter allocated to your drive.

```
d:
```

it should look something like this

[image]

hit enter

*if you have everything in the same drive as where windows was installed, skip this step and move on to Step 5*

**Step 5**

type in or copy-paste

```
ren *. *.png
```

**How it works**

ren = short for rename

*. = the original extension, since we don't have any, leave it blank

*.png = the extension we want to change it to)

and your problem should be fixed

**If you are using PowerShell in windows, please use the commands provided by Markus as a comment below this post**

Comment: I'm getting an [error](https://i.imgur.com/panJefw.png) for this: `ren : Cannot rename because item at '*.' does not exist.`, what works for me: `Dir | rename-item -newname  { $_.Name +".png" }` on Windows 10.

Comment: sorry about that Markus
I've updated the answer
turns out command prompt commands and powershell commands are a bit different
sorry about that

Comment: Yes, I never learned Powershell (the command above I googled)... One more thing is `cd` will not be enough if you're not on the same drive, you need to type `d:` as well in your example (though the OP has the files on desktop on C drive)

Answer (score 4):

I see you rendered all your files to desktop. To make sure you don't break some other files than the animation, as well that you keep those files in case something in the script goes wrong, create a new folder on the desktop called `animation`, and **copy** those files to that folder. Now in Blender, *Scripting* workspace, paste the code below and run it:

```py
import os
 
folder = "C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/animation"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    src =f"{folder}/{filename}"
    dst = f"{src}.png"
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

This should add the extensions to the files. For future renders, check this thread: [PNG animation render, saving images without a file type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109379/png-animation-render-saving-images-without-a-file-type)